# How to extract properties of layer transformation in After Effects

Tags: adobe, after-effects

So basically, I have a project in after effects that involves some transformation on different layers. My aim is to retrieve all sequential values of transformation (mainly position, scale, rotation) in json or some tabular data (csv, xlsx). I got stuck since I haven't ever work with AE in deep, so I would be grateful to receive an answer which will give me a good point to start.

To make the flow clear, I attach the image which reflects to my main aim of research. The required fields to parse is underlined [image]